# Use of word Art and Arts

Tags: grammatical-number

I am designing a logo for a client. She is an artist who wants to sell her paintings online. Her business is named "Art by Nita."

However, I'm not sure why she calls it "Art by Nina." What is the difference between "art" or "arts" in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming is explicitly off-topic per the Help Center.

Comment: This may be a better fit for our ELL site, but I think it's borderline.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 I'm not sure if that's necessary, this is more about the difference between "art" and "arts." The fact that it's part of a name is only background info.

Comment: Text in a logo of a t-shirt in reference to a business is **naming**, pure and simple. Logos do not have to follow any rules. @Azor

Comment: @user9825893y50932 We'll agree to disagree on that point, then.

Comment: Business logos do not and often on purpose do not have to follow normal rules of English. This is a naming question, since it is about the naming of a logo. As such, it is off-topic here. For an example of **arts by** see [Arts by Alexander](http://www.artsbyalexander.com/). Other answers have said it can only be *art by*, but this one example (Arts by Alexander) shows this is not the case.

Comment: @Mazhar - I suggested an edit to your question that removes the request for advice on what to name your business, since we don't provide advice on that, but changed it to a question that's more answerable here. || It's also typical to wait more than a few minutes to accept an answer, so that more people have a chance to see your question (only 11 have so far!) and give a good answer.

Comment: @Azor Ahai. I agree that this should not be considered a 'naming' request. However, no research is shown, and the question is almost certainly pretty basic at the level OP is asking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I flagged it for migration to ELL and I think it would be on topic there. I answered because I thought my answer would go with it, but now I'm reading that it wouldn't. Anyway, I'd be happy to see it moved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally Arts refers to the group of artistic disciplines; painting, sculpting etc. but can also refer to the liberal arts as in poetry, literature etc. The plural would not be correct.

Plural in her case would mean "Works of art by Nita" which is not what she asked for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Elliot 

So 'Art (singular) by Nita' would be okay in this case?

Answer (score -2):

Well, it depends on what exactly Nita produces. I assumed that since she was a single artist, she would generally work in a single medium, although I suppose it's possible that's not true. Instead of issuing a recommendation on what your client should name her business (since that is off-topic), I'll explain the difference between "art" and arts" in English.

"**Arts**" in English is meant more abstractly than plain "art" and refers to multiple disciplines of art.

For example, from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/art):

> The various branches of creative activity, such as painting, music, literature, and dance.

This means you don't use "arts" to refer to multiple pieces of artwork in English.

For example, you would never say "*Her *arts* are gorgeous," you would always say "Her *art* is gorgeous."
You could say "pieces of art" or maybe "art pieces," (at least according to this article: [20 of the World's Most Famous Art Pieces](http://historylists.org/art/20-of-the-world%E2%80%99s-most-famous-art-pieces.html)).

"**Art**," on the other hand is a mass noun. Again, from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/art):

> The expression or application of human creative skill and imagination, typically in a visual form such as painting or sculpture, producing works to be appreciated primarily for their beauty or emotional power.

Comment: Proper link and fomatting: [arts by](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arts+by%22&). Note this is a cursory search, not meant to address the issue in detail--since to me this is an open and shut case of VTC question. **Arts by Alexander** in said search seems apropos.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 I removed the recommendation on what the name should be, since you're right, that is off-topic. However, I do think the underlying question is fine, so I focused on answering that one.